# RegEx must include initial UC letter (not G-M), could include digits (max 4), but must include hyphen or underscore before digits

Tags: regex

Couldn't decipher all the RegEx stuff I searched: This is as close as I could get, but it allows more than one UC

```
/^([A-F | N-Z]\d._-]{1,6})$/
```

I've also explored the 'negative' version

```
/^[^G-M]/
```

but I'm not clear on how to attach the - or _ + digit option.

(This was a puzzle posed to me and I'm cheating)

Answer (score 0):

Try this one

```
/^UC[^G-M]*[-_]\d{0,4}$/
```

Comment: This will match `UC.:?&123456_` that is not wanted.

Answer (score 0):

If it can only include one letter, one hyphen or underscore, and up to four digits:

```
/^[A-FN-Z][-_]\d{0,4}$/
```

Comment: This will match `.:?&123456_` that is not wanted.

Answer (score 0):

How about:

```
^
  [A-FN-Z]    : RegEx must include initial UC letter (not G-M)
  [-_]        : must include hyphen or underscore before digits
  \d{0,4}     : include digits (max 4)
$
```

You may want to replace `\d{0,4}` by `\d{1,4}` if you need to have at least one digit.

According to your comment:

```
^[A-FN-Z](?:[-_]\d{0,4})?$
```

makes hyphen or underscore and digits optionnal

Comment: I kept chugging on this and these two are what I came up with - the other below answers don't allow for single UC letter only with digits being optional(requiring preceding - or _)
/^[A-F | N-Z]([_|/-]\d{1,4})?$/   or  /^[A-F | N-Z]([_|-]\d{1,4})?$/  both seem to work when I tested [here:](http://www.trans4mind.com/personal_development/JavaScript/Regular%20ExpressionsTester.htm)